# PHP Intermittent failure changing a string data type into a date using date_create

Tags: php, date

My code is Intermittently having problems with date_create.

I have some data that I am importing from another source.  The dates were entered with a two digit year.  But most of the dates are pre 1970, so they are being advanced to the 2000 century.  These are birth dates.  So for the dates that are greater than today, I am just subtracting 100 years.  Also, the dates that are being imported are strings instead of a date/time form.

My problem started when I did the strtotime and subtracted 100 years.  $dob lost the date type and changed to string.  So I was using the date_create to change it back to a date/time type.

I understand from the error that the boolean value is just the result of the attempted conversion.

I am eventually going to take the full record with name, address, dob, etc... and write it to my table.

```
$dob = date_create_from_format('d/m/y', $row["birthdate"]);
if ($dob === FALSE) {
    die("Converting Birthdate to date format failed for ".$row["id"]);
}
if (strtotime($row["birthdate"]) > time()) {
    echo date_format($dob, 'd/m/Y')." Date is greater than today<br>";
    $dob = strtotime($row["birthdate"].' -100 year');
    echo $dob."<br>";
    $dob = date_create(date('d/m/Y', $dob));
    if ($dob === FALSE) {
        echo "date_create failed<br>";
    }
    echo "New date is: ".date_format($dob, 'd/m/Y')."<br>"; //THIS IS LINE 209
} else {
    echo date_format($dob, 'd/m/Y')." Date is not greater than today<br>";
}
echo $firstName." ".$lastName." ".date_format($dob, 'd/m/Y')."<br>"; //THIS IS LINE 213
```

Here is the result of the code (which is just debug information):

```
06/01/2031 Date is greater than today
-1217703600
New date is: 06/01/1931
First Last 06/01/1931

01/06/2066 Date is greater than today
-125776800
New date is: 01/06/1966
First Last 01/06/1966

06/11/2032 Date is greater than today
-1185217200
New date is: 06/11/1932
First Last 06/11/1932

02/04/2033 Date is greater than today
-1225735200
date_create failed

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home2/lpenrod/public_html/larrydev.info/admin/ingest_clients.php on line 209
New date is: 

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home2/lpenrod/public_html/larrydev.info/admin/ingest_clients.php on line 213
First Last 

02/04/2033 Date is greater than today
-1225735200
date_create failed

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home2/lpenrod/public_html/larrydev.info/admin/ingest_clients.php on line 209
New date is: 

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home2/lpenrod/public_html/larrydev.info/admin/ingest_clients.php on line 213
First Last 

12/11/2029 Date is greater than today
-1294596000
date_create failed

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home2/lpenrod/public_html/larrydev.info/admin/ingest_clients.php on line 209
New date is: 

Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home2/lpenrod/public_html/larrydev.info/admin/ingest_clients.php on line 213
First Last 

08/04/2027 Date is greater than today
-1338404400
New date is: 08/04/1927
First Last 08/04/1927
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example written by using the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. The usage of the `DateTime` class comes handy when you wish to perform some complex tasks like [subtracting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php), calculating [differences](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) ( `DateTime` objects can be compared using the comparison operators ), [formatting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) etc. Also, `DateTime` objects are not affected by [Y2K38](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) problem ( except, of course, the [`getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php) method ).

```
$rows = array( 
    array( 'birthdate' => '06/01/31' ),
    array( 'birthdate' => '01/06/66' ),
    array( 'birthdate' => '06/11/32' ),
    array( 'birthdate' => '12/11/29' ),
    array( 'birthdate' => '08/04/27' ),
    array( 'birthdate' => '02/04/82' )
);

foreach( $rows as $row ) {

    if ( !$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/y', $row["birthdate"] ) )
        die( "Converting Birthdate to date format failed for ".$row["birthdate"] );

    if ( $dob > new DateTime() ) {
        echo $dob->format( 'd/m/Y' ) . " Date is greater than today<br>";

        if ( $dob->sub( new DateInterval('P100Y') ) ) echo "New date is: ".$dob->format( 'd/m/Y' )."<br>";
        else echo "date sub failed<br>";        

    } else {
        echo $dob->format( 'd/m/Y' )." Date is not greater than today<br>";
    }

    echo $dob->format( 'd/m/Y' )."<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
06/01/2031 Date is greater than today
New date is: 06/01/1931
06/01/1931
01/06/2066 Date is greater than today
New date is: 01/06/1966
01/06/1966
06/11/2032 Date is greater than today
New date is: 06/11/1932
06/11/1932
12/11/2029 Date is greater than today
New date is: 12/11/1929
12/11/1929
08/04/2027 Date is greater than today
New date is: 08/04/1927
08/04/1927
02/04/1982 Date is not greater than today
02/04/1982
```